# StartupDevelopment class is not being used because program.cs says to use Startup class when my environment is Development

Tags: c#, .net-core

I am on a Mac using dotnet Core 2.0

I would like to use a different database on my local development machine, like sqlite and SQL Server on staging and production.

I can have the following appsettings.json files: appsettings.Development.json, appsettings.Staging.json, and appsettings.json for development, staging, and production respectively.

In each of the files I want a different database like sqlite for development and SQLServer for staging and production, including different migrations.

My development environment is set to Development via an environment variable. When I run dotnet run I can confirm the hosting environment is Hosting environment: Development

In my program.cs file I have the following code

```
public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            BuildWebHost(args).Run();
        }

        public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .Build();
    }
```

I have a class called StartupDevelopment

```
public class StartupDevelopment 
    {
        public StartupDevelopment(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc();

            services.AddDbContext<MvcTriviaContext>(options =>
                                                    options.UseSqlite(Configuration.GetConnectionString("dbContext")));
        }
}
```

When I debug my application the constructor of the class Starup is called instead of StartupDevelopment.

Now I do not want to change program.cs because then i would have to change that for each environment.

I want the code to use StartupDevelopment when my environment is set to Development.

[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/startup) says

> An alternative to injecting IHostingEnvironment is to use a
>   conventions-based approach. The app can define separate Startup
>   classes for different environments (for example, StartupDevelopment),
>   and the appropriate startup class is selected at runtime.

I don't understand what am I doing wrong? How do I make the app use `StartupDevelopment` when my environment is Development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm on Windows, and I get the same behavior that you are seeing.

What worked was changing `UsesStartup<Startup>` to `UsesStartup(typeof(Startup).Assembly.FullName)` in Program.cs. The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments) is not clear about this, but I think if you specify a startup type that forces Asp.Net Core to use that type and not use conventions for finding the startup type.

Comment: I found out that we will run into issues going down this path. I could not get dotnet aspnet-generator to create new controllers. Using different methods like ConfigureDevelopmentServvices or ConfigureStagingServices is better as it works with dotnet aspnet-generator

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using StartupDevelopment it is better to use ConfigureDevelopmentServices method in Startup.cs. This way our program.cs remains untouched and this solution works with dotnet aspen-codegenerator when creating controllers.